# Facebook Post - Post in Personal Page and Business Page automatically or post in Business Page and automatically in Personal Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is it possible to Post in Facebook on my Personal Page and Facebook automatically post the same on my Business Page?

I was saying that i created a page in my tablet and saw that possibility.

I haven´t clicked then i was searching for a possible way to link my posts(in Personal and Business Page) and can´t find it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible by using a third-party app or service, I'm not aware of many but I do know that if you [connect your Facebook account to Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31113-how-to-use-twitter-with-facebook), you can Tweet to your personal Timeline and business page simultaneously.

Another thing you can do is post on your business page and then share it on your personal Timeline (to public or whatever you wish), allowing the post to be viewed on both the business page and your Timeline. This also has the advantage of giving the post on the business page 1 share.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About posting in twitter and connect to my facebook page i think is a good idea, but the problem is that i need to write more than 140 characters in a single post. About the second option, i tried to post in business page and then share but it only posts and only gets shared in business page. I used "@" but doesn´t show my name.